# Can anyone explain for which purpose we are using Protection Level as dangerous in the manifest file

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have mentioned **Protection level** as ***dangerous*** in the manifest for camera permission.But it works as usual in my application. Here is the code

```
<permission
            android:name="com.home.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/hint_camera"
            android:description="@string/sol_camera"
            android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.CAMERA"
            android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
```

Can you explain why we are using it.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html

Any dangerous permissions requested by an application may be displayed to the user and require confirmation before proceeding.

Comment: without mentioning protection level as dangerous  in the manifest. I can able to request permissions, then what the need of it.